# Angular Cli and Ionic 3 with Node.js version

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am developing in both ionic3 and angular.

Node.js version: v6.12.2

Warning when angular project starts: You are running version v6.12.2 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI v6.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 8.9 and greater.

Then i upgrade node.js version..

Node.js version: v10.4.1

Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Node.js 10.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

What should I do to get both to work together smoothly?

Comment: you need to rebuild your node sass, as it was built with the previous version `npm rebuild node-sass`

Comment: go to project folder then execute `npm rebuild node-sass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either run `npm install` again to run the post-install script of `node-sass` or you

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

to rebuild your node-sass with the current installed node